# Which composition of functions is the right one?

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

This question seems a bit stupid but I am really confused:
Let $f$ be a function and $g(z):=f(z)-f(2z)$.

What is $g(-1/z)$?
Is it $f(-1/z)-f(-2/z)$ or $f(z)-f(-1/(2z))$?

Thank you!

Comment: You might find it helpful to involve more symbols. Define $g(x)=f(x)-f(2x)$.
Let $x=-1/z$. Then, $x=-1/z$ and $2x=2\times(-1/z)=-2/z$ so that
$g(-1/z)=f(-1/z)-f(-2/z)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You blindly substitute the occurences of $z$ in the $g$ function WITH parenthesis around $z$ when the occurence is not trivial and then do some algebra to possibly simplify it.
$$
g(-1/z) = f(-1/z) - f(2 (-1/z)) = f(-1/z) - f(-2/z)
$$